# Is BasicDBObject.parse() secure against NoSQL injection attacks?

Tags: mongodb, security, mongo-java

I'm using the mongo-java-driver for connection to my MongoDB.
So my questions are about using MongoDB with a Java client:

- Is `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse(userInput)` secure against NoSQL injection attacks?
- Or do I have to sanitize the userInput String before parsing?
- If I have to sanitize the input: Are there special methods for sanitizing shipped with mongo-java-driver?
- Or shall I use `basicDBObject.put( "foo", "bar" )` instead?

The [MongoDB documentation describes a *strict mode*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/):

- Does this *strict mode* sanitize the input?
- How do I activate the strict mode when parsing?

The [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) describe several MongoDB injection attacks.
And it is unclear, if `BasicDBObject.parse()` sanitizes the input itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse() is not safe against NOSQL Injection
2. sanitizing is a good thing  for fighting against Injection in general but is not enought
3. There is some OWASP guidelines here for fighting NOSQL Injection : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet_in_Java#Example_-_MongoDB

I recommend you to have a look at Hibernate OGM if you want to do parametrization of the query : http://hibernate.org/ogm/documentation/. Parametrization is the only solution for fighting Injection